# Attempt to present <UIAlertController: > on <ViewController:> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, alert, uialertaction, researchkit

I am working on a project using ResearchKit, so I send the user into the task I create:

```
let taskViewController = ORKTaskViewController(task: SurveyTask, taskRunUUID: nil)
taskViewController.delegate = self
presentViewController(taskViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When the user is finished with the survey, he goes into:

```
func taskViewController(taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, didFinishWithReason reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, error: NSError?) {
    switch reason {
        case .Completed:
```

...
}

Here I encounter a problem when I try to show an alert before

```
taskViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

I get the below error:

*Attempt to present UIAlertController: ... on ViewController: ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy*

Any idea of how I could present the alert before dismissing the ViewController?

I use the below for the alert:

```
let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Houps", message: "Could not connect to the server.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**EDIT**:
The code is as below:

```
if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                print("HTTP response: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 201 {
                    taskViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }
            } else {
                print("No HTTP response")
                let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Houps", message: "Could not connect to the server.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
                presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
```

Comment: Could you dismiss the view controller on the click of the "OK" button in your alert controller?

Comment: I do not want to dismiss yet, I first want to show on alert. The dismissing is working just fine.
The problem is showing the alert.

Comment: Yes, and @j.f. is saying to dismiss when tapping "OK" on the alert.

Comment: Right, you show the alert, and then when the user clicks the "OK" button on the alert, dismiss the view controller.

Comment: I can't show the alert. Sorry for not explaining better. I get problems showing the alert.

Comment: Yep, your problem is because you are trying to present the alert controller on a view controller that has now been dismissed, hence the "not in the window hierarchy" error.

Comment: I have put an edit on the question to show how the code for the alert looks like and maybe for better explaining why I need to show the alert without dismissing.

Comment: Is there additional, relevant code that we can't see? From the snippet you provided, it looks like either the view controller is dismissed, _or_ you present the alert controller - which should work.

Comment: The presenting of the alert does not work. It gives the error in the title: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: > on <ViewController:> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call presentViewController on the taskViewController:ORKTaskViewController object

```
taskViewController.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

What object contains the httpResponse definition? The presentViewController() call looks like it's implicitly capturing self, on a view controller instance whose view perhaps is no longer in the view hierarchy when the response arrives.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(yourAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

for presenting the UIAlertController.